# Create a combination of 3 different chart with a reverse bar chart using chart js

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, linechart

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.2/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
<script>

    var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');

    var gradient1 = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);
    var gradient2 = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);

    gradient1.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(221, 239, 228, 1)');
    gradient2.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(230, 243, 243, 1)');


    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
          backgroundColor: gradient1,
          borderColor:'rgba(143, 203, 96, 1)',
          label: 'Max Temperature',
          fill: true,
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
          pointStyle: 'circle',
          pointRadius: 10,
          pointHoverRadius: 15
        },
        {
          backgroundColor: gradient2,
          borderColor:'rgba(3, 140, 140, 1)',
          label: 'Min Temperature',
          fill: true,
          data: [22, 29, 13, 15, 12, 13],
          pointStyle: 'circle',
          pointRadius: 10,
          pointHoverRadius: 15

        }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
        y: {
      beginAtZero: true,
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Y-Axis Label',
         font: {
            size: 25
          }

      }
    },
    x: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'X-Axis Label',
        font: {
            size: 25
          }
      }
    }

        },
        tension: 0.3
      }
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

i am new to java script and trying to create a chart with combination of 3 charts in one
the problem is I am unable to do the reverse bar chart

the expected result

[image: expected result]

Comment: Please show what you tried?

Comment: I have added my code kindly check

Comment: Why is python tagged?

Comment: because I working in a python project but currently I need to use java script due to some portion